# Name value pair table vs parent child

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, parent-child, name-value

I want to store about 100k rows of data, and all data some common field.
All data have a category and other fields is base on category.

For example if data is in category 1, It had `extrafield1` and `extrafield2`

I search and found two way for storing data.

**1-Name value pair**

```
Table1
ID    Name     Category   Field2           Field3
1     Name1    1          Value            Value
2     Name2    2          Value            Value

Table2 
ID    Table1_ID         Name           Value
1     1                 extrafield1    1
2     1                 extrafield2    2
3     1                 extrafield3    3
4     2                 extrafield4    4
5     2                 extrafield5    5
```

**2-Parent Child table**

```
Table1
ID    Name     Category   Field2           Field3
1     Name1    1          Value            Value
2     Name2    2          Value            Value

Tableforcategory1 
ID    Table1_ID         extrafield1    extrafield2     extrafield3
1     1                 1              2               3


Tableforcategory2 
ID    Table1_ID         extrafield4    extrafield5
1     2                 4              5
```

So my question is when use **method 1** and when use **method 2**.

Comment: If you use Postgres you could use a single table with a column for each attribute that belongs to all categories and one `hstore` (key/value) column to store the extra attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 is generally preferred for a variety of reasons:

- It more closely models the entities represented by the different categories.
- It allows for the columns to have different data types.
- It makes it easier to implement check constraints for value-only columns.
- It makes it easier to implement foreign key constraints for reference columns.
- It makes it easier to implement unique constraints, should these be appropriate.
- It makes it easier to implement not-NULL and default values.
- It makes it easier to add columns on specific attribute values.

And there may be other reasons.

The first method -- which is called entity-attribute-value modeling (EAV) -- is definitely an alternative.  It is mostly suitable in two situations:

- The number of attributes exceeds the column limit in the database being used.
- The attributes are sparsely populated, so only a few are in use for any given entity.

Sometimes a hybrid of these two methods is appropriate, with commonly used attributes being stored in a relational format and sparse attributes stored as EAV.

There are alternative approaches, such as storing the values in a JSON or XML object.  These are not generally recommended, but might be suitable in some databases under certain circumstances -- particularly when all attributes need to be treated as a single block and returned and set together.

Comment: I have another question, If i have only 4 category and I need use all extra field use method 2 ? and if I have a lot of category use method 1 ?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use EAV unless you ave a good reason for choosing it.

Comment: if I have a lot of category, in method 2 i should create a lot of table, Is it good reason to use EAV ?

Comment: @CooPer . . . Each category would be a separate *row* not a separate *column*.  Don't confuse entities and attributes.

Comment: All fields is base on category. if `category = 1` then i have extrafield1 extrafield2 , if `category=2` i have extrafield3 ... . and in method 2, i must create a table for each category. is it good reason to use method 1 when i have a lot of category ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of queries and the stability of the data model.

If your queries are essentially static, meaning you know when you are going to use "extrafield_x", then method 1 is simpler and more efficient, but less flexible.

If you need more dynamic queries and in time you might more categories and more "extrafields", method 1 is more flexible, no data model maintenance required, but more complex to use and probably slower.